# react-virtualized Masonry: how to scroll to index programmatically?

Tags: scroll, masonry, react-virtualized

I've tried `<Masonry ... scrollToIndex={myIndex} />` and `<Masonry ... scrollTop={myIndex}`, with no success.

Is there a public method, or some other prop I should use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Masonry doesn't support this.  In my case, List turned out to be what I needed, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44524350/how-do-i-tell-the-masonry-component-that-its-cells-have-changed-their-height).